# wpdb Cannot Update column in Database

Tags: php, database, wpdb

In the custom table, I try to update a specific column with using $wpdb->update class and using HTML form for updating one column that has same id (in here dlname Is ID of data ).

The problem is this When I trying to update the column in my table using HTML form The page only will Refresh

**BUT When I manually set ID in codes and THEN typing and submitting new value by HTML form it will work like charm.**

**It seems to be machine cannot understand the value that inputted from the form** This is my code :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btnUpdate'])){
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name='wp_AR_tb_name';

    $data_array = array(

    'dstatus' => $_POST['dstatuschange'],
    'downloadname' => $_POST['dlname'],

    );

    $data_where = array('downloadname' =>'dlname');
    $wpdb->update($table_name,$data_array,$data_where);
}
```

And this is my Form :

```
<form method="POST">

    <label> Input One : </label>
    <input type="text" name="dlname"/>

    <label> Input Two : </label>
    <input type="text" name="dstatuschange" />

    <button type="submit" name="btnUpdate"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

Comment: What is data type of `dlname` in db?  https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows may help. Pay attension to `format` and `where_format`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, an observation: the line highlighted below is correct as per your logic? This query will set the `dstatus` and `downloadname` fields in a row as `$_POST['dstatuschange']` and `$_POST['dlname']` **if** `downloadname` field is the `'dlname'` string. Maybe you wanted to put the `$_POST['dlname']` variable in your `WHERE` condition?

Second, wordpress custom POSTs work much better if you use the standard wordpress way to manage them. Look at [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/319043/how-to-handle-a-custom-form-in-wordpress-to-submit-to-another-page) to see how to handle properly a custom form submission.

Comment: The line i highlighted is my logic . Yeah i wanna update the row `WHERE` My `downloadname` is equal with inputted value from the html form in `dlname` . And about custom post you offered me : unfortunately we can't change our plugin base in this time and the point where we stand now. Is there possible to figured it out with this code ?

Comment: Thank you @Fabrizio There is need to put `$_POST['dlname'] ` in `$data_where`  as you pointed to and it will work fine.

and this [link](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wpdb-cannot-update-column-in-database/#post-11240040) Have the Same Solution.